# JS YUI: How to do column sorting of a datatable on the click of a button?

Tags: javascript, html, yui, yui3, columnsorting

**Background:-**
I picked up the script in the following piece of code for table sorting from [here](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/datatable/datatable-sort.html). Now I want a little change in the way it works.

**Question:-**
*I want the data to be **sorted on the basis of the user's selection from a drop down list (of column names) rather than clicking on the column headers in the table.*** **How can I do that?**

**In a nutshell, the output I have is in the first attached image, the output I want is in the second image.**

**Explained:-**
We can see that clicking on the column header (the top cell in the column) sorts the data in that column (and in the table according to that column).

*What I want is that the column headers should just be descriptive titles for the column and clicking on them should do nothing; while there should be a drop-down list/menu button at the top of the table (separate from the table, just a separate drop-down list button/html select element), containing the list of column names. The data in the table should sort according the column name selected by the user from that list.*

**CODE:**-

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>Simple Tabbed Menu by CSS-Tricks</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/3.17.2/build/yui/yui-min.js"></script>
</head>

<body class="yui3-skin-sam">
    <script>
            YUI().use("datatable-sort", function (Y) {

            var cols = [{
                key: "Company",
                label: "Click to Sort Column A",
                sortable: true
            }, {
                key: "Phone",
                label: "Not Sortable Column B",
                sortable: true
            }, {
                key: "Contact",
                label: "Click to Sort Column C",
                sortable: true
            }],

            data = [{
                Company: "Company Bee",
                Phone: "415-555-1234",
                Contact: "Sally Spencer"
            }, {
                Company: "Acme Company",
                Phone: "650-555-4444",
                Contact: "John Jones"
            }, {
                Company: "Industrial Industries",
                Phone: "408-555-5678",
                Contact: "Robin Smith"
            }],

            table = new Y.DataTable({
                columns: cols,
                data: data,
                summary: "Contacts list",
                caption: "Table with simple column sorting"
            }).render("#sort");
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

**IMAGES:-**

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to add a `<select>` drop-down menu and listen to the `change` event with the [`Node.on()`](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/api/classes/Node.html#method_on) method. You can pass `Node.on()` a function which sorts the columns with [`DataTable.sort()`](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/api/classes/DataTable.html#method_sort).

```
<select id="select">
    <option value="">Sort by...</option>
    <option value="Company">Sort A</option>
    <option value="Phone">Sort B</option>
    <option value="Contact">Sort C</option>
</select>
<script>
    YUI.use('datatable-sort', function(Y) {

        var /* your code here ...*/
        table = new Y.DataTable({ /* datatable code here ... */ }),
        select = Y.one('#select');

        select.on('change', function(event) {

            var value = select.get('value');

            if (value) {
                table.sort(value);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Here's a runnable example using your code:

```js
YUI().use("datatable-sort", function (Y) {
    var cols = [{
        key: "Company",
        label: "Click to Sort Column A",
        sortable: true
    }, {
        key: "Phone",
        label: "Not Sortable Column B",
        sortable: true
    }, {
        key: "Contact",
        label: "Click to Sort Column C",
        sortable: true
    }],

        data = [{
            Company: "Company Bee",
            Phone: "415-555-1234",
            Contact: "Sally Spencer"
        }, {
            Company: "Acme Company",
            Phone: "650-555-4444",
            Contact: "John Jones"
        }, {
            Company: "Industrial Industries",
            Phone: "408-555-5678",
            Contact: "Robin Smith"
        }],

        table = new Y.DataTable({
            columns: cols,
            data: data,
            summary: "Contacts list",
            caption: "Table with simple column sorting"
        }).render("#sort"),

        select = Y.one('#select');

    select.on('change', function (event) {

        var value = select.get('value');

        if (value) {
            table.sort(value);
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/stiemannkj1/0214fdc4cccaa77d6e504320cf70a571/raw/63d260364730fb067f103c00862c7e65685256df/yui-3.18.1_build_yui_yui-min.js"></script>
<body class="yui3-skin-sam">
    <select id="select">
        <option value="">Sort by...</option>
        <option value="Company">Sort A</option>
        <option value="Phone">Sort B</option>
        <option value="Contact">Sort C</option>
    </select>
    <div id="sort"></div>
</body>
```

You may also want to update the drop-down when one of the columns is sorted. To do that, you should listen to the [`sort` event of the `DataTable`](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/api/classes/DataTable.html#event_sort), and update the `DataTable` based on that.